# string indices must be integers - Python 3.6

Tags: string, python-3.x, csv, set

I am learning python and doing some practice on the titanic statistics data. The file can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzC4seE8zx2UNV9GUG4wSGhqaGM). While running this simple code i am always getting this error message 'string indices must be integers'.
I want to find the total number of unique data entries in my .csv file according to PassengerId'. When i checked my 'test_data' variable it has 'PassengerId' in it but still i am getting error. How can i solve it?

```
import pandas as pd

titanic_df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")

unique_number_df = set()

for test_data in titanic_df:

       unique_number_df.add(test_data['PassengerId'])

print(len(unique_number_df))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
titanic_df = pd.read_csv("titanic_data.csv")

unique_number_df = set()

for test_data in titanic_df["PassengerId"]: #here you should pass the column name.

        unique_number_df.add(test_data)

print(len(unique_number_df))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for the Suggestion next time I will do.